# What does vim try to tell me with: 'Sorry, this command is disabled, the Pythons's site module could not be loaded'?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, vimscript-python

I try to get python support in gvim on windows to work with the help of [this](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/) binary distribution.
First I got the error `python27.dll could not be located`, what I successfully fixed by copying `python27.dll` to the `vim74` directory.
 Although `:echo has('python')` returns 1 now, if I try to execute `:py print(1)` I get this error:

> Sorry, this command is disabled, the Pythons's site module could not be loaded

I just don't understand what Vim is trying to tell me by that and what the problem is.

I'm using `vim 7.4.1817 64bit` with `+python/dyn` & `+python3/dyn` and `python 2.7.9 64bit` (the newer `python 2.7.11 64bit` produces the same behaviour)

Comment: Did you install a "full" python "distribution"? If not, do so, if yes, don't move the DLL to Vim, but make the path to python executables/dlls folder available to Vim by adding it to Windows PATH environment variable. Also check if you don't have *other* python distribution path in PATH, and remove it.

Comment: what do you consider a 'full' python 'distribution'. I never installed python before, but ill add it to my path

Comment: E.g. something downloadable from here: http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads (just an example) (of course, restart Vim after modifying Windows' PATH).

Comment: I downloaded the 64bit installer from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/). Adding the python directory to my path produces the same behaviour as copying the dll as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed gvim from [here](https://bintray.com/micbou/generic/vim) and `Python 2.7.9` and it works like a charm now.
I will further try to make it portable and edit the question if I succeed

**From my experience trying to get `python` in gvim under windows to work, I have to say that there seems to be a problem with the 2.7.11 version and gvim 7.4.x**

Answer (score 0):

Running with the Chocolatey package `vim-tux` on Windows 7, I was getting the same error. I fixed the problem by running [this command](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/blob/master/appveyor.bat#L89-L91) (be warned: this is registry editing):

```
reg copy HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7 HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7-32 /s /reg:64
```

I found this solution on [this forum](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/57883).

Comment: I will look into it and see if it helps